# Exchange determinant and integral of a matrix-valued function

Tags: matrices, inequalities, determinants

Assume $A(x)=(a_{ij}(x))_{k\times k}$ is a Hermitian matrix function on some manifold $M$, is there any inequality relates the integral of its determinant $\int_M \det(A)$ and the determinant of its integral $\det(\int_M A)$? Here $\int_M A$ is the matrix obtained by integrating each entries, i.e. $\int_M A=(\int_M a_{ij}(x)dx)_{k\times k}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course, there are. Suppose $A(x)$ is semi-positive definite. Then, because of the concavity of $A\mapsto(\det A)^{1/n}$, Jenssen's Inequality gives
$$\frac1{{\rm vol}M}\int_M(\det A)^{1/n}\le\det\left(\frac1{{\rm vol}M}\int A(x)\right)^{1/n}.$$

On the other hand, if $A$ is a constant $B$ plus the Jacobian matrix of a compactly supported field $\phi$ (for instance if $M$ has no boundary), then the integral and the determinant do commutte:
$$\frac1{{\rm vol}M}\int_M\det(B+ \nabla\phi)=\det B.$$
There are variations on this theme (quasi-convexity in the sense of Morrey, polyconvexity in the sense of Ball).

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, many thanks @Denis

Comment: in the inequality, will $vol M$ cancel out on both sides?

Comment: @M.Lin. Dividing by the volume of $M$ is necessary for the validity of the equality. Think to the case $\phi\equiv0$.